# How can I use API-Gateway as reverse proxy of CloudSearch?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudsearch

I would like to use API-Gateway to solve two problems for directly accessing CloudSearch

1. enable CORS (which CloudSearch does not seem to have an out-of-box solution)
2. open the query only to authenticated users (API-Gateway's authorizer can achieve this)

Here is my question: do I need to use lambda function to invoke the CloudSearch or can I directly set the HTTP integration at API-Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

As you can integrate HTTP endpoint from API gateway you can directly call HTTP instead of going through Lambda